# Resolving operator ambiguity

Tags: c++, data-structures, directx, operator-overloading

I have the following map type...

```
std::map<D3DXCOLOR, ID3DXMesh*>
```

During compilation, xfunctional complains that it **cannot resolve an ambiguity** regarding the key type;

```
error C2593: 'operator <' is ambiguous
```

The candidate operators detected by the compiler are as follows;

1. built-in C++ operator<(DWORD, DWORD)
2. built-in C++ operator<(FLOAT, FLOAT)
3. built-in C++ operator<(D3DCOLORVALUE, D3DCOLORVALUE)

The D3DXCOLOR struct consists of 4 floats **r**, **g**, **b**, and **a** respectively but does not define a operator <. It does however provide cast functions for DWORD FLOAT and  D3DCOLORVALUE, hence the entries in the candidate list.

I am contemplating the best way to resolve this problem. I could write my own inline operator for D3DXCOLOR, wrap the colour inside a new class which provides its own operator <, or is it possible to somehow hint to the compiler which implementation should be chosen from the list of candidates? The DWORD operator < would meet my requirements adequately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options. Supposing for example that you want them compared as colorvalues:

1) Define `operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const D3DXCOLOR &lhs, const D3DXCOLOR &rhs) {
    return static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(lhs) < static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(rhs);
}
```

2) Specialize `std::less`:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct less<D3DXCOLOR> {
        bool operator()(const D3DXCOLOR &lhs, const D3DXCOLOR &rhs) {
            return static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(lhs) < static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(rhs);
        }
    };
}
```

3) Supply a third template parameter to your map - note that this changes the type of the map, so if you pass the map around a lot this might be inconvenient. But it expresses that the ordering is to be used only for this map, not as the canonical "correct" order of colors for any other purpose.

```
struct mycomparator {
    bool operator()(const D3DXCOLOR &lhs, const D3DXCOLOR &rhs) {
        return static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(lhs) < static_cast<D3DCOLORVALUE>(rhs);
    }    
};

std::map<D3DXCOLOR, ID3DXMesh*, mycomparator>
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. As the map is used only internally to my object I have opted to provide the map with a comparator functor object whose implementation casts both lhs and rhs to DWORD when performing the < operation.

Comment: The second solution is quite arcane - I'm not sure if you'd really *want* to specialize `std::less` but not overload `operator<` to match. It means that `std::map` and `std::set` "just work" for the type, but ordinary comparison doesn't, which might be appropriate when the order you've defined is basically arbitrary just for the purpose of having one at all. But it also means that functional-style programming works as a side effect, using the basically arbitrary order, which is kind of dangerous if there's a good reason not to provide `operator<`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass a less-than functor to the `map` class template that should be used.

```
struct D3DXCOLOR_less {
    bool operator ()(D3DXCOLOR const&a, D3DXCOLOR const& b) const { … }
};

std::map<D3DXCOLOR, ID3DXMesh*, D3DXCOLOR_less> foo;
```

This is definitely what I would do in this case, unless you also need the `operator <` for this class in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own operator<, or provide a comparator functor to the map.

```
struct CompareColor {
  bool operator()(D3DXCOLOR const & L, D3DXCOLOR const & R) const {
    // Compare and return whether L is less than R
  }
}

map<D3DXCOLOR, ID3DXMesh*, CompareColor> TheMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `operator<` function for `D3DXCOLOR`, as

```
bool operator<(const D3DXCOLOR &c1, const D3DXCOLOR &c2)
{
   return <some boolean value>;
}
```

Or define a **compare** functor, something called `D3DXCOLOR_LESS` and pass it as third parameter to the `std::map`:

```
struct D3DXCOLOR_LESS
{
    bool operator()(const D3DXCOLOR &c1, const D3DXCOLOR &c2)
    {
       return <some boolean value>;
    }
};

std::map<D3DXCOLOR, ID3DXMesh*, D3DXCOLOR_LESS>  colormap;
```

Comment: This will polute meaning of `operator<` because there is no standart way to order colors in one row.

Comment: @ony: What do you mean by *polute meaning of operator<*? Whatever you write in `operator()`, you can write that in `operator<`. What is the big deal?

Comment: Difference between `::D3DXCOLOR_myorder::operator(..)` and `::operator<(..)` is that last one is global symbol. So if some library will use this operator for say decide how colors forms the clusters then you'll make two algorithm tighten up together without any meaningful relation between them. And there is no reason for std::map variant of ordering to be the default/general/main.

Answer (score 0):

Actually RGBA color have no some default quasi-order like any scalar. And you shouldn't define one in global context, but you can define your own ordering and specify it in std::map template instance. See parameters description at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html